# Force a function to be real

Tags: function-construction, complex

I have a multivariable function in Mathematica that arises as an eigenvalue of a matrix. It involves square roots of the variables involved, but Mathematica automatically assumes such a function to be of complex variables.

Is there a way I can force mathematica to assume a function can only take real components?

Comment: use `ComplexExpand`? _ComplexExpand[expr] expands expr assuming that all variables are real._

Comment: The correct solution depends on what exactly you are doing with this function (ComplexExpand, Assuming, Assumptions, 3rd argument of Reduce, Re/Im, etc.). More information is needed before this can be answered. Ideally, give a short example.

Comment: For instance `f[a_, b_, c_, d_] := (Sqrt[a^(2 d ) (a/b)^d + (1 + 2 I) b^2 c^2 ])`

Comment: So the problem is, that if I take `Abs` or integrate this kind of function over some variable, it automatically assumes variables to be complex? How can I restrict so this function only contains real parameters?

Comment: So you haven't seen `Assuming[]` yet?

Comment: I tried it with say `a \[Element] Reals` but to no avail.